# CefSharp browser .net behaves erratic when href link contains no target definition

Tags: html, .net, cefsharp

I have a small .NET application using CefSharp browser. I am injecting some JavaScript with my application to read some values from the target site.

This works really very nicely and I am very happy with it.

Now I came across a strange problem and I wonder if there is a workaround for it.

If I click on any site from this list, all works OK:
http://websdr.org/

But if I scroll down to the bottom of that page there is a map canvas showing google maps markers and if I click on one to open it there is a popup window showing the link.

When I click on that link I am redirected to the same site as if I would chose it from the simple text based list above.

So far so good - but when I access it via the world map popup link CefSharp starts acting erratic, for eaxample the page title property ramains on the previous site and I cannot inject any JavaScript to the newly opened site in the browser anymore. (the opened new site is showing however fine inside the browser).

I noticed the table links to the target site like this:

```html
<a href="http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/" target="_top">http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/</a>
```

While the world map accesses the site like this:

```html
<a href="http://websdr2.utahsdr.org:8901/">http://websdr2.utahsdr.org:8901/</a>
```

Obviously the href link from the worldmap is missing any target definition...

Any clues how I can make CefSharp work correctly with both ways of accessing the site? (with target it works, without specified target it doesn't)

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I just noticed that it is not only a CefSharp specific problem, when I do the same navigating in Google Chrome it behaves the same - it opens the new link, but the page title remains that of the previous page.....hmmm :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the author of the website to kindly change the target formate and now the problem is solved (unfortunately not in CEFSharp, but more in general)